# ZFS Recover from 2 dead drives on Raidz1-0

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, raid10

I've got a ZFS pool I'm trying to import to a new install, and I have what looks like 2 dead drives out of 4. Considering I have no back up (I know, this array *was* my backups) is there a chance of recovering from this?
See below for `zfs import` from new machine.

```
   pool: Yggdrasil
 id: 9361495856877653960


 state: UNAVAIL
 status: The pool was last accessed by another system.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-EY
 config:

    Yggdrasil                                     UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
      raidz1-0                                    UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
        ata-WDC_WD40EZRX-00SPEB0_WD-WCC4EKDAD274  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD40EZRX-00SPEB0_WD-WCC4EKPTEHUN  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD40EZRX-00SPEB0_WD-WCC4ELYS3HR6  UNAVAIL
        ata-WDC_WD40EZRX-00SPEB0_WD-WCC4ELYS3U15  UNAVAIL
```

Thanks.

Comment: The chance is zero. What happened to the drives? They don't appear to be plugged in.

Comment: They don't come up in BIOS either. I might try moving the around on different SATA ports, and check my power supply, but I'm not hopeful.